# Live app icons on smartphones?

Tags: icons, mobile-application

One thing on my iPhone that always makes me wonder is the Clock app icon. As far as I know, it is the only app icon that is actually "live" (**constantly changing state** to show the current time). There is also the Settings icon, with gears rotating, although only when updating. On Android, I don't know any app with this kind of behaviour, besides **Calendar showing the current date**.

I could not find any information regarding this feature in [Apple Human-Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/app-icon/). I am not an iOS developer, so I am not sure whether this is even accessible to third-part developers or it is just reserved for system apps.

Basically I am curious about the UX implications of this feature. **Is there any study regarding "live" app icons? Why don't Apple/Google or designers use it for more app icons?**

(Also, do feature has a specific name? I used "live" based on Microsoft's live tiles.)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it doesn't appear to be in the guidelines, and also I've never seen a third-party app with a "live" app icon would lead me to believe that they (thankfully) do not make that available to third-party developers.

[With iOS 14](https://www.apple.com/ios/ios-14/), however, they did implement something (which Android has had for a while now) to accomplish a similar "live" effect: **widgets**. These are significantly larger than an app icon's size, so there is sufficient room to convey a useful amount of up-to-date, relevant data. I haven't looked into the restrictions placed on developers for [capabilities and limitations of widgets](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/system-capabilities/widgets/), but from what I've seen so far, they appear to be mostly static text and/or images—not so much in the way of animations, like your iOS-native examples.